# Como alterar a função explode para importar arquivo .txt utilizando dois pontos

Tags: php

Como fazer a função: `explode(',', $linha);` importar um arquivo .txt separados por dois pontos em um arquivo .txt ao invés de usar a vírgula.

O arquivo .txt atualmente é este

```
Cesar, cesar@celke.com.br, cesar, 123456
Kelly, kelly@celke.com.br, kelly, 123457
Jessica, jessica@celke.com.br, jessica, 123458
```

A ideia seria ficar dessa forma

```
Cesar:cesar@celke.com.br:cesar:123456
Kelly:kelly@celke.com.br:kelly:123457
Jessica:jessica@celke.com.br:jessica:123458
```

Código php

```
//Incluir a conexao com BD
include_once("conexao.php");

//Receber os dados do formulário
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

//ler todo o arquivo para um array
$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

//Ler os dados do array
foreach($dados as $linha){
    //Retirar os espaços em branco no inicio e no final da string
    $linha = trim($linha);
    //Colocar em um array cada item separado pela virgula na string
    $valor = explode(',', $linha);

    //Recuperar o valor do array indicando qual posição do array requerido e atribuindo para um variável
    $nome = $valor[0];
    $email = $valor[1];
    $usuario = $valor[2];
    $senha = $valor[3];

    //Criar a QUERY com PHP para inserir os dados no banco de dados
    $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, usuario, senha) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$usuario', '$senha')";

    //Executar a QUERY para inserir os registros no banco de dados com MySQLi
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);  
}
//Criar a variável global com a mensagem de sucesso
$_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color: green;'>Carregado os dados com sucesso!</p>";
//Redirecionar o usuário com PHP para a página index.php
header("Location: index.php");
```

Ao enviar o arquivo .txt para o servidor separando os dados de nome, e-mail e senha com dois pontos e sem espaços toda informação é apenas inserida no campo nome do banco de dados.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Voce aceitaria uma resposta que utiliza apenas o comando via shell? (Sem utilizar php). Minha sugestão é utilizar o `sed`.

Comment: Troca `explode(',', $linha);` por `explode(':', $linha);`.

Comment: @Benilson ao alterar para dois pontos ele importa tudo em uma só coluna no banco de dados como mostrei na imagem do phpmyadmin.

Comment: O arquivo está com `:`ou `,`? Não ficou claro. Você quer alterar o arquivo txt com `,` para `:` ou ele já está assim?

Comment: @TiagoA Está com dois pontos. O problema é que com dois pontos ele importa todos os dados para só uma coluna, quando deveria separar por nome, email, usuário e senha.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste aqui online e funcionou com seu código: https://repl.it/@tiagoa/txt-dois-pontos

Comment: @TiagoA Funcionou mesmo, obrigado.

Comment: o ideal seria fazer um único INSERT fora do FOREACH.

Comment: ao invés de Criar a QUERY dentro do loop crie os VALUES do insert

Comment: $dataString .= " ('$nome', '$email', '$usuario', '$senha'),";

Comment: fora do loop retire a ultima virgula  $values=substr($dataString, 0, -1);

Comment: e faça o insert assim:  $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, usuario, senha) VALUES $values";

Comment: como dito anteriormente, faça o insert fora do loop

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Obrigado pelas dicas, vou acrescentar no código.